# Remove all subscribers from email sent from marketing cloud Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm creating a journey in marketing cloud where I want to send the email to the lead in the journey only. But when I choose the option to add email in the journey it asks me to add a publication list where I have to add All subscribers.
I don't want to send the email to anyone else other than one single lead in the entry source.

How to achieve this?

Comment: What are you using for your entry source?

Comment: @TomCallahan, I'm using "Salesforce Data" as the entry source. Basically I want to send email as soon as the lead is created or updated in Salesforce.

Comment: Even though you have the Cloud connector, SalesCloud leads are created as subscribers when you initiate emails.  The `Lead ID` is used as the `subscriberkey` automatically.

Comment: @TomCallahan, if the lead is not present in MArketing cloud and only present in Salesforce(Created or updated) so will the Journey consider the created or updated record in Journey entry source in Marketing cloud?